# This program must raise the number two to a power that the user enters

Tags: recursion, multiplication, exponentiation

```
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'result'. 21  
Warning C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'result'. 12    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'number'. 58

When raised to a power higher than 3 biological errors.
```

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
```

Column multiplication function.
First and second warning is here.

```
void MultiplyArrays(int* ar1, int* len1, int* ar2, int len2) {
        int resultLen = *len1 + len2;
        int* result = new int[resultLen]();
        for (int i = *len1-1; i > -1; --i) {
            int carry = 0;
            for (int j = len2-1; j > -1; --j) {
                int tempSum = result[i + j + 1] + ar1[i] * ar2[i] + carry;
                result[i + j + 1] = tempSum % 10;
                carry = tempSum / 10;
            }
            result[i] += carry;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (i<resultLen && result[i]==0)
            ++i;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            result[j] = result[j + i];
            --resultLen;
        }
        *len1 = resultLen;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
            ar1[i] = result[i];
        }
        delete[] result;
    }
```

Recursive exponentiation function.

```
void RaisePowerTwo(int* len, int* array, int power) {
        if (power == 1)
            array[0] = 2;
        else if (power % 2 == 1) {
            RaisePowerTwo(len, array, power - 1);
            int* timeAr = new int[1];
            timeAr[0] = 2;
            MultiplyArrays(array, len, timeAr, 1);
            delete[] timeAr;
        }
        else if (power % 2 == 0) {
            RaisePowerTwo(len, array, power / 2);
            MultiplyArrays(array, len, array, *len);
        }
    }
```

Main function.
Third warning is here

```
 int main() {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int length = 1;
        int* number = new int[length]();
        RaisePowerTwo(&length, number, n);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            cout << number[i];
            delete[] number;
            return 0;
        }
```

Please help, I've been struggling with this problem for two weeks now. Only today I thought of asking a question on Stask Overflow, this is my first question.

Comment: Which lines do the warnings refer to?

Comment: In lines 12,21,58

Comment: As you have not provided the code in a single block, what are those lines?

Comment: int tempSum = result[i + j + 1] + ar1[i] * ar2[i] + carry;

Comment: result[j] = result[j + i];

Comment: cout << number[i];

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other bugs, but the main issue is that you copy a longer array into a shorter array, and thereby write data outside the range of the shorter array. It happens in this piece of code in `MultiplyArrays`:

```c
    *len1 = resultLen;
    for (int i = 0; i < resultLen; i++) {
        ar1[i] = result[i];
    }
```

Here `ar1` has "only" a size of `*len1` (before it is overwritten by `resultLen`), while you are writing to `ar1[resultLen-1]` which can be an out-of-range index for `ar1`. Realise that this `ar1` is the `number` array that you defined in `main` and can only hold one integer. You need to allocate memory for the growing array.

In C++ you should use `vector` for this purpose.

Some of the other issues are:

- `ar2[i]` is wrong. The right index to use is `j`.
- `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {` is a wrong. It doesn't take into account how many values there are in the result array.
- [Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5459839)

Here is a correction, using `vector`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> MultiplyArrays(std::vector<int> v1, std::vector<int> v2) {
    std::vector<int> result(v1.size() + v2.size(), 0);
    for (int i = v1.size() - 1; i > -1; --i) {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int j = v2.size() - 1; j > -1; --j) {
            // index issue
            int tempSum = result[i + j + 1] + v1[i] * v2[j] + carry;
            result[i + j + 1] = tempSum % 10;
            carry = tempSum / 10;
        }
        result[i] += carry;
    }
    while (result[0] == 0)
        result.erase(result.begin());
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> RaisePowerTwo(int power) {
    if (power == 0) { // We can use 0 as base case
        std::vector<int> v = {1};
        return v;
    }
    else if (power % 2 == 1) {
        std::vector<int> two = {2};
        return MultiplyArrays(RaisePowerTwo(power - 1), two);
    }
    else { // No need for condition here
        std::vector<int> root = RaisePowerTwo(power / 2);
        return MultiplyArrays(root, root);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> number = RaisePowerTwo(n);
    for (int val : number)
        std::cout << val;
    return 0;
}
```